# Survey webpart in sp 2013 does not opened in a dialog

Tags: survey

I am using sp 2013. I have created a new survey and add some questions. When I try to answer the questions the questions are showed inside the page. But I enabled the dialog option. It looks like it is not working. Is this a bug in sp? Is there some workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Launch forms in a dialog?` has no effect.

Workaround is to use JavaScript along with `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`

Answer (score 0):

If click on respond to this survey from `overview.aspx` page, dialog box will not work.

If you go to `allitems.aspx` and then click on respond to this survey, dialog box option will work. I tested this on my SharePoint Online environment.

`https://SITENAME/Lists/testsurvey/overview.aspx` => Dialog doesnt work
`https://SITENAME/Lists/testsurvey/AllItems.aspx` => Dialog works